# Computing the maximum number given the number of digits in an input

Tags: javascript, math

I am writing a function in JavaScript to input "bad values" into a text field to verify that the text field won't take those values and will correctly show an error.

My original function looked like this:

```
// I think every single function here is a function I wrote, 
// so hopefully the names will be clear enough to describe what they're doing.

/**
 * @param {Object} cObject - Object for specific field.
 * @param {Number} max - Maximum numeric value that can populate field.
 */
function fieldCheck(cObject, max)
{
    let min = cObject.maxValue + 1,
        positiveNumber = math.getRandomFloat(min, max, math.getRandomInt(1, 5)).toString(),
        negativeNumber = math.getRandomFloat((-1 * max), (-1 * (min + 1)), math.getRandomInt(1, 4)).toString();
    
    inputFunction(positiveNumber, cObject);
    verifyNotInTextBox(positiveNumber, cObject);
    inputFunction(negativeNumber, cObject);
    verifyNotInTextBox(negativeNumber, cObject);
}
```

So, if there is a field that holds only integer values from 0 to 359, then I would call the function like this:

`fieldCheck(fieldObject, 999);`

Or if there was a field that held float values from 0 to 179, then I would call the function like this:

`fieldCheck(fieldObject, 999.9999);`

I started thinking that the "max" parameter seemed to be superfluous. The min value after all was determined using a property of the cObject argument. Each of these objects have a minValue and maxValue property that holds the minimum value allowed in the field and the maximum value allowed in the field. I figured that there should be a way to compute the max parameter inside the function and only need the "cObject" parameter.

The only way I've come up with to do this is just concatenating "9"s onto an empty string based on the length of the `maxValue` property.

```
let min = cObject.maxValue + 1,
    max = "";

for (let i = 0; i < min.toString().length; i++)
{
    max = max.concat("9");
}

max = Number(max);
```

This is more or less "fine". Except that when I try to implement this for those float fields then it ends up looking more like this:

```
let min = cObject.maxValue + 1,
    max = "",
    fieldLength = 8;

for (let i = 0; i < min.toString().length; i++)
{
    max = max.concat("9");
}

max = max.concat(".");

for (i = max.length; i < fieldLength; i++)
{
    max = max.concat("9");
}

max = Number(max);
```

This just feels sloppy to me and screams at there needing to be a much better, more efficient way to come at this.

SIDE NOTE: Some of that math in the original function may not work out perfectly for both function examples. I actually have two functions for float fields and int fields simply because the float fields require additional tests with random strings that the int fields don't. So I get that a random float wouldn't make that much sense for those, but hopefully that doesn't detract from the actual meat of the question.

EDIT: Comments made it clear that I didn't write this very clearly. I've written up what should be a reproduceable example that should show in code what I asked above. This runs in my IDE, but I haven't gotten it to run in any of the free online ones for what that's worth.

```js
feuxFieldObject = {
  name: "Field Name: ",
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 359
}


function getRandomInt(min, max, base = 10) {
  let minimum = Math.ceil(parseInt(Number(min).toString(), base));
  let maximum = Math.floor(parseInt(Number(max).toString(), base)) + 1;
  let result;

  result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum);
  result = Number(result.toString(base));

  return result;
}


function fieldCheck_Original(cObject, max) {
  let min = cObject.maxValue + 1;
  positiveNumber = getRandomInt(min, max);
  negativeNumber = getRandomInt((-1 * max), (-1 * (min + 1)));

  console.log(positiveNumber.toString());
  positiveNumber > feuxFieldObject.maxValue ?
    console.log("PASS: Invalid Entry") :
    console.log("FAIL: Valid Entry");
  console.log(negativeNumber.toString());
  negativeNumber < feuxFieldObject.minValue ?
    console.log("PASS: Invalid Entry") :
    console.log("FAIL: Valid Entry");
}

fieldCheck_Original(feuxFieldObject, 999);

function fieldCheck_New(cObject) {
  let min = cObject.maxValue + 1,
    max = "",
    fieldLength = 8;

  for (let i = 0; i < min.toString().length; i++) {
    max = max.concat("9");
  }

  max = max.concat(".");

  for (i = max.length; i < fieldLength; i++) {
    max = max.concat("9");
  }

  max = Number(max);

  let positiveNumber = getRandomInt(min, max),
    negativeNumber = getRandomInt((-1 * max), (-1 * (min + 1)));

  console.log(positiveNumber.toString());
  positiveNumber > feuxFieldObject.maxValue ?
    console.log("PASS: Invalid Entry") :
    console.log("FAIL: Valid Entry");
  console.log(negativeNumber.toString());
  negativeNumber < feuxFieldObject.minValue ?
    console.log("PASS: Invalid Entry") :
    console.log("FAIL: Valid Entry");
}

fieldCheck_New(feuxFieldObject);
```

Comment: We have no idea what is in the `cObject` object, BTW. If there is an actual numeric value that represents the maximum allowed value, it should be easy enough to generate a number that is higher than that, whether all 9s or not.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: If the element has a max value set, why do you need to calculate it??? Maybe I am missing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm going to add in a reproduceable example using some basic stand in object for the "cObject" argument.

Comment: The  only problem with the code you have is that `textboxType` is not defined. Changing it to any value makes the snippet work fine.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I should have taken it out. It's defined elsewhere in code. I also just realized that Stack Overflow has the option to run the code from here. That would have saved me time if I'd noticed that. It should work now. The console.log's are intended to replicate the idea of entering text in a field. The "Invalid Entry"'s are there to show what it should show if you're entering that into a field in the app.

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure what an answer here would be. You could use fewer lines of code by using `"9".repeat()` instead of `for (...) { max.concat("9") }` but it's not going to be that much more efficient unless you have millions of fields. And really, all you need is a value greater than `maxValue`, so just get a random number (from 1 to +Infinity), add it to `maxValue` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Except that I need it to be bound to the number of digits present in maxValue. The maximum allowable value in this example field is 359, which means I need to test random values between 360 and 999. The catch, is coding this so that it takes basically any value found in maxValue.

Comment: But why do you need to test with 999 or 752 or 518? Won't a test that you are unable to enter 360 be sufficient? As long as you verify that the value is not greater than 359, that meets those validation criteria. If you want to separately verify a length validation, that could be done without messing about with the other validation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I assume the software can do unexpected things with unexpected code combinations. The code is old and full of spaghetti. I test all values from 360 - 999 in this example because I don't want to assume that if I can't enter 360 that I couldn't also enter 361.